# How to get the content of a span element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-parsing, dom-traversal, dom, jquery-traversing

When a text is clicked on my page, I want to get the value of the nearest (going upwards) span element with the class of 'network_ip'. Here is my code:

```
<div class="ip_header">
<div style="margin-left:30px;">
<div class="flag_and_ip">
<img title="United Kingdom" src="/gearbox/component/ui/htdocs_zend/public/img/mini-flags/gb.gif">
<span class="network_ip">213.171.218.xxx</span>
</div>
<div class="align_count">48</div>
IPs,
<div class="align_count">63</div>
Domains
</div>
</div>
<div class="network_ip_content ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="height: 4417.6px; display: block;" role="tabpanel">
<h4>
213.171.218.97 (
<b>1</b>
Domains)
</h4>
<p>
<a href="http://private.dnsstuff.com/tools/whois.ch?ip=213.171.218.97&src=ShowIP" target="_blank">IP Whois</a>
,
<a href="http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=ip%3A213.171.218.97" target="_blank">IP Neighbours</a>
</p>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a class="domain" href="#">studentjetpacks.com</a>
</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here my attempt in jQuery so far:

```
    $(".domain").click(function(){ 
    $("div#list_lm_domain_urls_dialog").dialog('open');
    var domain = $(this).text();
    var network_ip = $(this).closest('span.network_ip').text();

    alert(network_ip);
    refresh_lm_domain_links(domain,0,100);
    return false;                   
});
```

The alert comes up with nothing.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to traverse your dom to find the element.. since who knows what divs your span is inside.. you aren't showing your whole structure as I see 2 extra closing divs

Comment: down vote
 

The problem that you're having is that the network_ip isn't an ancestor of domain. You have to find a common ancestor and it is hard to tell what that is since your HTML sample is incomplete here.

Comment: @wirey Apologies, I've amended this now. The span element which I'm interested in, is in a div.flag_and_ip which is in a div with an inline style which is in a div.ip_header

Comment: @Sid I think you're missing the closing div around your table.. I added it in my anwer.  I explained how I traversed your structure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is this

```
$(this) // starting from the anchor
   .closest('div.network_ip_content ') // find div that wraps the table content
   .prevAll('.ip_header:first') // get first prev div sibling with class=ip_header
   .find('span.network_ip') // find the span
   .text() // get the text
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XJvZH/

Answer (score 0):

You really should find a better way of linking the anchor to the span - i.e. use IDs or `data-` attributes.

But since you asked for searching for the nearest `span` going upwards, here you go:

```
$(".domain").click(function(){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $("div#list_lm_domain_urls_dialog").dialog('open');
    var domain = $anchor.text();
    var network_ip;
    $anchor.parents().each(function(){
        var $spans = $(this).prevAll().find('span.network_ip');
        if ($spans.length>0) {
            network_ip = $spans.last().text()
            return false;
        }
    });

    alert(network_ip);
    refresh_lm_domain_links(domain,0,100);

    return false;
});
```

This takes all the parents of the anchor and loops from the nearest parent upwards. For each parent it checks previous siblings using `.prevAll()` and looks for the span. Finally, it takes the last from the found spans - i.e. the "bottom" span if there were more than one.

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/3DnDW/).